# macros - complex formula

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have the following excel formulae in different columns:

```
 = IF( OR(D2 <1000, D2 = 1000),"5","")
 = IF( AND(OR(D2 <10000, D2 = 10000 ), D2 >1000),"4","")
 = IF(AND(OR(D2 > 10000, D2 = 100000), D2 < 100000), "3","")
 = IF(AND(OR(D2 > 100000,D2 = 100000), D2 < 1000000),"2","")
 = IF(OR(D2 > 1000000,D4 = 1000000),"1","")
```

so total 5 columns.
I want to combine all these into 1 column. That is have one formula and only 1 column not 5.
Could some one please help me out with either clubbing all these formulae into 1 big one or help with writing a macro for it?

I tried combining them to 1 formula and could not achieve the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is `D4` a typo?

```
= IF( OR(D2 <1000, D2 = 1000),"5", IF( AND(OR(D2 <10000, D2 = 10000 ), D2 >1000),"4", IF(AND(OR(D2 > 10000, D2 = 100000), D2 < 100000), "3", IF(AND(OR(D2 > 100000,D2 = 100000), D2 < 1000000),"2", IF(OR(D2 > 1000000,D4 = 1000000),"1","")))))
```

Comment: yes. gr8!!! thank you so much! I got so thouroughly confused with this :P. Thanks again